# Tag <label> does not work for <input>

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

Why does not work the tag ? Where is error?

**ANSWER**

There was an error with duplication ID, when I used fancybox library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I receive a new modal window, but it does not delete the old data, so there is the duplication id.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to see a code sample but I am assuming that there is some structure issues within your HTML. Your label and input tags should follow something like this:

```
<label for="username">Click me</label>
<input type="text" id="username">
```

Answer (score 0):

For radio buttons, the `id` of each must be unique, and the `for` attribute must match it. I took a sample from the URL you provided (and then deleted?) and set the `id` to be unique (`<input id="r1a"`) and matched it to the label (`<label for="r1a">`):

```
<input class="point" id="r1a" type="radio" name="radio2" onchange="check_selected('2')">
<label class="point" for="r1a">Замена с окраской</label>
```

It worked just fine.

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
 <tr>
<td><label>Name</label></td>
<td><input type="radio"/></td>
</tr>
```

Your problem is happen due to top or bottom, you miss some table tag,
And If you miss any table tag i.e TR, TD, then table is miss behave with data.

Please check again your table code or share here your code, (Your provided link is not opening)

I you share code here, you get perfect answer within minutes.

Best regards,

Comment: It is look find on my computer, can you send screenshot, for I am not understand website language.

Comment: That is wrong. A `<label>` needs a `for` attribute that matches the targeted element's `id`, or the `<label>` needs to wrap the text and the field.